# Requiring salary information and medical history before first job interview

Tags: professionalism, company-culture, japan, law

Rakuten Japan is asking all candidates to fill out the following forms before their first interview, including, for instance, itemized salary information from your current or previous position (verification [源泉徴収票] may be requested later) and your medical history.

http://global.rakuten.com/careers/files/sd/[Name][Rakuten]_Recruiting_questionnaire.doc (English, There is also a Japanese version of this document, but for some reason I am not able to post more than 2 links in this question)

http://global.rakuten.com/corp/careers/files/Health_Check_Sheet.xlsx (Japanese and English)

According to the Rakuten HR people these documents are “necessary in the selection process” i.e. you will not be able to continue the selection process without submitting this information.

According to the Rakuten Privacy Policy for Recruitment Activities that candidates must accept before submitting an online application, “…the Rakuten Group Company reserves the right to retain such information to the fullest extent required or permitted by law”, regardless of the results of the selection process.

Apparently sense of privacy is not among the dimensions along which Rakuten aims at “diversifying … the people we employ” (Hiroshi Mikitani, Market Place 3.0: Rewriting the Rules of Borderless Business, p.65). Is it common – or legal – in Japan to require itemized salary information from your current or previous position and medical history as a precondition for continuing the selection process?

Comment: For the health check sheet I noticed it says "this process will not affect your selection of applications" and it also includes a box which says "not applicable for all of the above." One approach would be to check that box and don't even read the list.

Comment: You have already asked a question about this here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58170/requiring-itemized-salary-information-and-medical-history-before-first-job-inter Please do not submit another similar question. Please edit the previous one and wait to see if it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Although I have no clue about Japan's privacy laws, I think it's a safe bet to assume that a company that reaches a certain size will not be dumb enough to behave in an obviously illegal way in public. As the process of collecting medical data is made public and it's not some shady interviewer asking about it in some backroom, it's very, very likely indeed legal.